# Not displaying graph

Tags: php, mysql, graph, plot

I followed this tutorial http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/documentation/tutorial-mysql-and-phpgraphlib. I ran my code but it displays the destroyed image. I want to fetch data from the database and to generate line graph. I downloaded the phpgraphlib and libgd packages. I also extracted the `phpgraphlib.php` file in htdocs and pear folders and I also found in `php.ini` file the `php_gd2.dll` is uncommented (no semicolon).

graph.php

```
  <?php

      include("phpgraphlib.php");
      $graph=new PHPGraphLib(400,300);

      //connection to MySQL database

      $link =mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Could not connect :'. mysql_error());

     //select db
     mysql_selected_db('mynewdb') or die('Could not select database');

     $dataArray=array();

     //get data from database
     $sql="SELECT year1,year2,crit FROM scores WHERE sid='13'";
     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

   if ($result) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             $crit=$row["crit"];
             $year1=$row["year1"];
             $year2=$row["year2"];
             $count=$row["count"];
            //add to data array
            $dataArray[$crit]=$count;
            }
   }

     //configure graph
      $graph->addData($dataArray);
      $graph->setTitle("Interesting Semester");
      $graph->addData($dataArray);
      $graph->setBars(false);
      $graph->setDataPoints(true);
      $graph->setDataPointColor('maroon');
      $graph->setDataValues(true);
      $graph->setDataValueColor('maroon');
      $graph->setGoalLine(.0025);
      $graph->setGoalLineColor('red');
      $graph->createGraph();

 ?>
```

Comment: what is in your db, what do you mean by destroyed, what were you expecting and what did you recieve

Comment: @Zielu In my db i save the score id, the year 1, the year 2 and a criteria. I want display a graph but I can't.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`